# Bootstrap css failed to load resource error 404

Tags: css, nginx, digital-ocean

First of all I am sorry for the title.

I deployed my flask app through Digital Ocean droplet but there's a problem where the bootstrap did not load. I already search through the internet regarding this problem and tried several way but did not work.

Below is the snippet of my code.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
....
....
<link rel="icon" href="../static/icon/favicon.ico">
<link href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../static/css/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
...
</head>
```

the link for the icon works great but for the css file, it didn't.

views.py

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/webapptest

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <droplet_ip_address>;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user1/project/webapptest/webapptest.sock;

    }
    location ^~ /static {
        root home/user1/project/webapptest/app/static;
    }

}
```

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) to serve my app on digitalocean. I am hoping maybe some of you can help me solving this problem. I believe I must had left something from these code but I do not know where.

The error looks like this when I checked using developer tools in Google chrome:

```
failed to load resource:the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://<droplet ip address>/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you're set on hosting bootstrap, then that's fine (although you're likely to deliver it slower than a CDN). The `root` directive needs an absolute path to the directory, so yours should read `/home/user1/project/webapptest/app/static;` (notice the *leading slash*) then you'll need a `try_files` directive to tell NGINX to try as a file, then as a directory, and then fallback to something `try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;` Another way around this is to use an `alias` instead of `root` like this `alias /home/user1/project/webapptest/app/static/;` (notice the *leading and trailing slash*)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what is going on there, but would it not be easier to just load bootstrap from free CDN like Maxi or [jsDevlivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/?query=bootstrap)? Last time I had something like this I had loaded none minified versions to the server.

change `href` to >

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

If you need some other version just change 3.3.7 to a version you need.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I tried your suggestion by replacing the `href` path to the link and restart nginx from the server but nothing happen. the web page still did not loading the css. Am I doing it wrong? Thank you for your help